# Bitwise-and with Hex and Character in Java

Tags: java

I need to convert a given integer (my integers are always less than 30000) to its corresponding hexadecimal value and then get the characters of that value. The output should have the length of 2 bytes.

**Ex1:**

- Interger value = 25135 (decimal Value)
- corresponding hexadecimal value = 622f ( 2 Bytes)
- Corresponding characters of the hexadecimal characters = b/ (hex 62 = char b and hex 2f = char /)

**Ex2:**

- Integer value = 207 (Decimal Value)
- corresponding hexadecimal value = CF ( 1 Byte)
- corresponding hexadecimal value(after padding for two bytes) = 00CF ( 2 Bytes)
- Corresponding characters of the hexadecimal characters = some non printable 2 characters(in log file it look like ^@ and I with dash)

The following C++ code works well in both above cases.

```
void WriteBinaryTag(char* _zBuf, int _iValue)
{
    unsigned short usValue = (unsigned short)_iValue;

    ((unsigned char*)_zBuf)[1] = (unsigned char)usValue & 0x00FF;
    usValue >>= 8;
    ((unsigned char*)_zBuf)[0] = (unsigned char)usValue & 0x00FF;
}
```

Now I need to do the same thing in Java and I did it in the following way.

```
public static char[] writeBinaryTag (int iTag) {
    char[] data = new char[2];
    data[1]= (char) (iTag & 0x00FF);
    iTag >>= 8;
    data[0]= (char) (iTag & 0x00FF);
    return data;
}
```

**Problem:**
I tested the above java method as follows.

```
char[] temp = writeBinaryTag(207);
StringBuilder frame = new StringBuilder();
frame.append(temp);
System.out.println("OUT1:"+207+":"+frame.toString()+"|");

char[] temp2 = writeBinaryTag(25135);
StringBuilder frame2 = new StringBuilder();
frame2.append(temp2);
System.out.println("OUT2:"+25135+":"+frame2.toString()+"|");
```

StringBuilder is used as I need to append several varialbes to same frame other than the above binary tags. Finally  I print the frame values as above. Then I analyze the printed log file using binaryviewer to look the corresponding hexadecimal values.
The problem is above java code works fine only for example 1 above(Value 25135 ) . For the example two (value 207) it produces:

- corresponding hexadecimal value as 00C38F ( 3 bytes it seems) instead of 00CF as produced by c++ code.

Can someone kindly help me to figure out the issue with the java code.

[image: Image 1 : Log output]

[image: Image 2 : Binary Viewer Analysis of above log output]

Answer (score 2):

You are not converting to Hexidecimal anywhere here. It appears you want to convert a 16-bit value into two bytes. (a `char` is a 16-bit value in Java)

The equivalent would be

```
void writeBinaryTag(byte[] zBuf, int _iValue) {
    zBuf[1] = (byte) _iValue;
    zBuf[0] = (byte) (_iValue >> 8);
}
```

Creating a byte[] just to do this is inefficient and almost certainly not what you want to be writing instead there is an API to do this.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ....order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.writeShort((short) _iValue);

// later to read an unsigned short
int iValue = bb.readShort() & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried as the first way you have suggested.( For testing purposes I just created the byte array inside the method)

`public static byte[] writeBinaryTag3( int _iValue) {
 byte[] zBuf = new byte[2];
 zBuf[1] = (byte) _iValue;
 zBuf[0] = (byte) (_iValue >> 8);
 return zBuf;
}`

But it produces something very long.

Ex: for 207 : 
 printed value :[B@13cd9466 
 Hex Values when anayze with binary file analyzer : 5B 42 40 31 33 63 64 39 34 36 36
 
 For 25125:
 Printed value : [B@1dc9beb2
 ex Values when anayze with binary file analyzer : 5B 42 40 31 64 63 39 63 65 62 32

Comment: @user1308004 unfortunately this is what `byte[].toString()` does.  If you want to print the numbers in decimal you need to use `Arrays.toString(zBuf)` If you want to print in hexidecimal, you need to write your own routine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanaton. Can you let me know why my previous code works for larger numbers such as 25135 but not for small numbers such as 207?

Comment: @user1308004 in both cases, you can only have two chars. It works equally well. for one or two byte values.  Can you say what the issue is?

Comment: For  25135 java method is working fine. That means corresponding hexadecimal value = 622f and Corresponding characters of the hexadecimal characters = b/ (hex 62 = char b and hex 2f = char /). But for 207 it not produce in the same way. corresponding hexadecimal value for 207 is CF. the Corresponding characters of those hexadecimal characters is some non printable 2 characters with c++ code(in log file it look like ^@ and I with dash) But with java code when analyze log file I can see 00C38F  for 207 insted of 00CF. That is the problem I have

Comment: @user1308004 in ALL cases you have just two values. for 207 you can only get 00 CF.  Can you explain which method returns anything but two values?  even if you give it an invalid number like -1 or 1234567890 it will still produce exact 2 bytes or 2 chars.

Comment: That is the java method given in my initial post. `public static char[] writeBinaryTag (int iTag) {
    char[] data = new char[2];
    data[1]= (char) (iTag & 0x00FF);
    iTag >>= 8;
    data[0]= (char) (iTag & 0x00FF);
    return data;
}`

Comment: @user1308004 the one which states `char[] data = new char[2];`  can you explain how this produces anything but 2 `char`?

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey: I have updated my original post with the highlighted problem details at the end. All the details on how I have checked the values are given there. Please look in to that.

Comment: @user1308004 I think you should decide if you want to be writing binary or text.  StringBuilder and String in general is for text.  You can use it from binary but only if you really know what you are doing.  In this case `0xCF` is  a character which is > 127 and must be encoded check you convert it to text.and display it need to use 2 bytes for this encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 1):

See I was working with some hardware interaction and at that time I have written different methods in util. It will helps for all different conversions as well.

```
 private static String binaryToHex(String bin) {
     return String.format("%X", Long.parseLong(bin,2)) ;
 }
```

---

```
public static String hexToBinary16Bit(String hex16bit) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex16bit, 16);
    String bin = toBinary(i);
    return String.format("%0d", Integer.parseInt(bin));
}
```

---

```
private static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return String.format("%08d", Integer.parseInt(bin));
}
```

---

```
private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

---

```
private static String hexBin(String hex) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    System.out.println(a);
    String finalBin = null;
    int bit=1;
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {

        sBuilder.append((((a&bit)==0)?0:1));
        finalBin = sBuilder.toString();
        bit*=2;
    }
return finalBin;
}
```

---

```
 public static String[] customSplit(String src) {
            String [] output = src.replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("   \\]","").split(",");

        for (String element : output) {
                System.out.println(element);
        }
    return output;
  }
```

---

```
    private static String hexToASCII(String hexValue) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < hexValue.length(); i += 2) {
                String str = hexValue.substring(i, i + 2);
                output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
    return output.toString();
   }
```

---

```
 public static String hexBin8bit(String hex) {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
        System.out.println(a);
        String finalBin = null;
        int bit=1;
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {

            sBuilder.append((((a&bit)==0)?0:1));
            finalBin = sBuilder.toString();
            bit*=2;
        }
    return finalBin;
    }
```

---

```
public static int toInt32(byte[] bytes, int index) throws Exception {
            if (bytes.length != 4)
                throw new Exception("The length of the byte array must be at least 4 bytes long.");
            return (int) ((int) (0xff & bytes[index]) << 56 | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 1]) << 48 | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 2]) << 40 | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 3]) << 32);
        }
```

---

public static byte[][] split(byte [] arrayIn, int len) {

```
    if (arrayIn == null) {
        return null;
    }

    boolean even = arrayIn.length % len == 0;

    int totalLength = arrayIn.length / len;

    if (!even)
        totalLength++;

    byte[][] newArray = new byte[totalLength][];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalLength; ++i) {
        int allocLength = len;
        if (!even && i == totalLength - 1)
            allocLength = arrayIn.length % len;
        newArray[i] = new byte[allocLength];
        System.arraycopy(arrayIn, i * len, newArray[i], 0, allocLength);
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

---

```
public static byte[][] split1dArray1(byte[] arr1D, int columnSize) {
            byte[][] arr2D = null;
            int rowSize = arr1D.length/columnSize;

            for(int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < columnSize; j++){
                    arr2D[i][j] = arr1D[i+j];
                }
            }

            return arr2D;
```

### }

```
public static byte[][] split1dArray2(byte[] arr1D, int columnSize) {
            int len=arr1D.length;

            if(len%512 !=0) {
                len= len/columnSize +1;
            } else {
                len=len/columnSize;
            }

            byte [][] arr2D= new byte [len][columnSize];

            int k=0;
            for(int i=0; i<=len-1; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<=columnSize-1; i++) {
                    arr2D[i][j]=arr1D[k];
                    k++;
                }   
            }
            return arr2D;
        }
```

---

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] hexByte) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < hexByte.length; i++)
                str.append(String.format("%x", hexByte[i]));
            return str.toString();
        }
```

---

```
private static byte [] test() {
    // Command String
    String hex = "84";

    //Creates the command byte array (Function #1)
    int NumberChars = hex.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2) {
        int x = i+2;
        bytes[i / 2] = new BigInteger(hex.substring(i, x),16).byteValue();
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: There is lots of methods here, but I can't see the one which relates to the question.

Comment: @Vid : can you kindly let me know which of these functions will match to my problem?

Comment: @user1308004 none of them do. -1